# getting error SIMD operation

Tags: c++, simd

I want to compute for `k=0` to `k=100`

```
A[j][k]=((A[j][k]-con*A[r][k])%2);
```

for that I am storing `(con*A[r][k])` in some `int temp[5]` 
and then doing `A[j][k]-temp[]` in SIMD whats wrong in the code below its giving segmentation fault for line  `__m128i m5=_mm_sub_epi32(*m3,*m4);`

```
while((k+4)<100)
{       
    __m128i *m3 = (__m128i*)A[j+k]; 

    temp[0]=con*A[r][k];
    temp[1]=con*A[r][k+1];
    temp[2]=con*A[r][k+2];
    temp[3]=con*A[r][k+3];

    __m128i *m4 = (__m128i*)temp;
    __m128i m5 =_mm_sub_epi32(*m3,*m4);
    (temp_ptr)=(int*)&m5;
    printf("%ld,%d,%ld\n",A[j][k],con,A[r][k]);

    A[j][k]  =temp_ptr[0]%2;
    A[j][k+1]=temp_ptr[1]%2;
    A[j][k+2]=temp_ptr[2]%2;
    A[j][k+3]=temp_ptr[3]%2;

    k=k+4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you didn't take care of the alignment. SIMD instructions require 16-byte alignment (see [this](http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html) article). Otherwise, your program will crash.

Either alignment, or you have wrong indexes somewhere, and access wrong memory.

Answer (score 1):

Without the possible values for j, k, and r it's hard to tell why, but most likely you are overindexing one of your arrays

Comment: over indexing arrays was not the problem i checked it

Comment: What are the dimensions of `A`? What are the possible values of `j` and `r`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement:

```
for (k = 0; k < 100; k += 4)
{
    A[j][k] = (A[j][k] - con * A[r][k]) % 2;
}
```

and you want to see some benefit from SIMD, then you need to do it all in SIMD, i.e. don't mix SIMD and scalar code.

For example (untested):

```
const __m128i vcon = _mm_set1_epi32(con);
const __m128i vk1 = _mm_set1_epi32(1);
for (k = 0; k < 100; k += 4)
{
    __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128(&A[j][k]); // load v1 from A[j][k..k+3] (misaligned)
    __m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128(&A[r][k]); // load v2 from A[r][k..k+3] (misaligned)

    v2 = _mm_mullo_epi32(v2, vcon);         // v2 = con * A[r][k..k+3]
    v1 = _mm_sub_epi32(v1, v2);             // v1 = A[j][k..k+3] - con * A[r][k..k+3]
    v1 = _mm_and_si128(v1, vk1);            // v1 = (A[j][k..k+3] - con * A[r][k..k+3]) % 2

    _mm_storeu_si128(&A[j][k], v1);         // store v1 back to A[j][k..k+3] (misaligned)
}
```

Note: if you can guarantee that each row of A is 16 byte aligned then you can change the misaligned loads/stores (`_mm_loadu_si128`/`_mm_storeu_si128`) to aligned loads/stores (`_mm_load_si128`/`_mm_store_si128`) - this will help performance somewhat, depending on what CPU you are targetting.